# Wrap a higher-order function in some context and apply it

Tags: swift, functional-programming

Similar, I believe, [to an applicative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Applicative_functor), I would like to wrap a higher-order function in some context and apply it to a sequence.

```swift
protocol Foo { func a() -> Void }

class Bar: Foo { func a() { } }

let seq = [Bar(), Bar(), Bar()]
```

Concretely, Give the above three definitions, I'd like to be able to call `dispatch(event)` where `dispatch` wraps up a `forEach` over a sequence of protocol instances, and `event` is a function defined by that protocol.

```swift
private func dispatch(event: () -> Void) -> Void {
    DispatchQueue.main.async { // context that the forEach mapping should happen inside of
        seq.forEach($0.event())
    }
}

let _ = dispatch(Foo.a)
```

Obviously, this doesn't work with Swift's type system (I'm used to [Clojure's apply()](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/apply)). As a possible alternative, is there a way to wrap the sequence into a partial that I can `forEach` on?

```swift
let dispatch() -> [Foo] {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        seq.forEach // ‍♂️
    }
}

let _ = dispatch { $0.a() }
```

Perhaps `dispatch` should be thought of as a constrained extension to `Sequence`?

```swift
extension Sequence where Iterator.Element == Foo {
    func dispatch() -> [Foo] { 
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            return self.forEach // ‍♀️
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know the terminology of functional programming, so I may have misunderstood the question. Are you trying to write a function that can invoke `.a()` of each `Foo` in the sequence, but whether it's `.a` or some other method is based on a parameter of dispatch?

Comment: @NewDev That's correct! I want the caller to be able to specify `a()`, or a potential `b()` etc.

Comment: One approach that would have helped you was to use a key path e.g. `\Bar.a`, but unfortunately key paths [cannot refer to instance methods](https://forums.swift.org/t/why-can-t-key-paths-refer-to-instance-methods/35315/26)

Comment: Can you explain your motivation a little? I'm trying to understand what you're trying to achieve here, because it's not clear to me what is meaningless place-holder, vs. what's just a simplifying example. One such question: What's the purpose of `Foo`? Why would you want to extend `Sequence` of `Foo`s?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While not as elegant as could have been with key paths to instance methods, you could also create a dispatch function that takes in a closure with each element as its parameter:

```
func dispatch(_ handler: @escaping (Foo) -> Void) {
   DispatchQueue.main.async {
      seq.forEach(handler)
   }
}
```

And invoke it like so:

```
dispatch { $0.a() }
```

Answer (score 1):

While you can't use `KeyPath` for instance methods, you can use it for properties, if it works for you.

You can change your protocol and implementation to something like this:

```
protocol Foo {
    var a: () -> Void { get }
}

class Bar: Foo {
    lazy var a = {
        print("Bar")
    }
}
```

Then you can define your `dispatch` function to take a `KeyPath` as parameter:

```
extension Sequence where Iterator.Element: Foo {
    func dispatch(keyPath: KeyPath<Foo, () -> Void>) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            forEach { $0[keyPath: keyPath]() }
        }
    }
}
```

and pass the properties `KeyPath` as parameter:

```
let seq = [Bar(), Bar(), Bar()]
seq.dispatch(keyPath: \Foo.a)
```

Comment: @NewDev good suggestion! I updated my answer. I preferred the `lazy` approach. Thank you.